# Assigning Event handlers in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik

I have derived from `Telerik's NumericUpDown` control and created a "myUpDown" control.
In the source code for my new controls class I have defined a Value changed event  handler

```
 this.ValueChanged += myUpDown_ValueChanged;
```

and then in XAML that I am using it(). Lets name this XAML as "blah.myView"
), have something like this:( there are more attributes set there, but the main part is like this

But when I compile this I get this compile error:

```
"Event handler myUpDown_ValueChanged not found on class blah.myView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a method with the same signature and name in the code behind of your XAML.

```
 void myUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RadRangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
///  do stuff
}
```